# Data is not fetching properly in SSG Next.js

Tags: next.js, static-site-generation

While creating the post (for the blog) using ***Jodit Editor***, I used to directly save it's output [(html string)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9thD.png) into mongo.

Then after adding SSG, at the build time, the (consoled) fetched data appears as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N885k.png).

Whereas simply fetching the api shows data correctly. [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHya0.png)

Code of ***getStaticProps*** & ***getStaticPaths***

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.post(baseUrl + getPostBySlug, { slug: params?.slug });

        console.log({ slug: params?.slug }, 'data 2 ->', data);    // here is the data consoled

        return {
            props: { post: data?.data ?? null },
            revalidate: 10,
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        return {
            props: { post: null },
            revalidate: 10,
        }
    }
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    try {
        const res = await fetch(baseUrl + getAllPosts, { method: 'GET' });
        const data = await res?.json();

        if (data?.success && data?.data) {
            return {
                paths: data?.data?.map(({ slug }) => ({ params: { slug } })),
                fallback: true,
            }
        }
        else {
            return {
                paths: [{ params: { slug: '/' } }],
                fallback: true,
            }
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        return {
            paths: [{ params: { slug: '/' } }],
            fallback: true,
        }
    }
}
```

Final output, a SSG page but with no data init -> [here](https://reaper-mks.vercel.app/article/test-2)

Comment: try to `console.log(data?.data)` inside your `getStaticProps` before returning

Comment: @AhmedSbai yeah, i have consoled it in 2nd line of getStaticProps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update to Axios ^1.2.1 - [there was an issue with previous versions](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5298).

You can set the headers as a temporary solution to prevent this from happening.

```js
await axios.post("your/api/url",{
 headers: { Accept: 'application/json', 'Accept-Encoding': 'identity' },
 { slug: "url-slug" }
)
```

Comment: Thanks, updating axios & adding these headers worked!